# Spring @Scheduled annotation method runs more than once in a given time

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring scheduled cron job is running twice in a scheduled time.

Using spring 4.2.5 version.

REST API -> Jersey + Spring Integration.

web.xml as below.

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>REST-Service-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>      
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>RESTController</param-value>
    </init-param>    
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.om.ResponseCorsFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST-Service-Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

spring application context xml file for the task entry.

```
<task:annotation-driven/>
```

Spring bean as follows.

```
@Component("springBean")
public class SpringBean {

@Scheduled(cron = "0 35 23 * * ?")
public void job() {....}
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] and explain how you detect it running twice.

Comment: If it is running twice you are loading your configuration twice...

Comment: If you define the "SpringBean" in configuration file, it will run twice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Problem resolved.

Solution: I was loading the same bean twice, so removed the duplicate bean.